# Sorting in SphinxSearch by attribute presence

Tags: sorting, sphinx

**Introduction**

I have unusual Sphinx need, I'm sorting results (users) only by attributes for example `group ASC, rating DESC` and of course with some filters for example `interests`.

In SQL relation users `n` interest.
In sphinx  interests is multi attribute with integers.

And all filtering and sorting is working great, but I need to do some upgrate:

**Problem**

User can have standard interest but now he can also have *main interest* which is marked in database by flag bool `is_main`.

Now I need to modify sorting from upper to users with main interest come first before users with standard interest.

Example for visualize:
* Filtering is by `sport` interest.

Results should be filtered by sport interest - and its easy part, but
*how to make results with attribute `sport=main` come first*?

My obvious solution is to make 2 queries one with additinal filter `main_interest` true, second false and merging results but it doesnt seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual attribute, the result of a condition, sort of like

```
$cl->setSelect("*,IF(attrib=34,1,0) as mysort");
or
$sphinxql = "SELECT *,IF(attrib=34,1,0) as mysort FROM myindex ...";
```

Then can just do `setSortOrder` or `ORDER BY` by  `mysort DESC, ...`

Its not clear if users can only have one 'main' interest - in which case you can stick it a scalar attribute. Or multiple, in which case need another MVA. So you could have one MVA with all interests (for filtering) and another with just the main interest (for sorting)

Comment: Thanks tips but creating MVA for sorting with only main interests dont solve problem because in this MVA we will have for example  id's (sportsID, computer gamesID, watching tvID) - this 3 interests are main from entire collection of 20 interests. If filtering is by 'sportID' we sort this MVA and result of sorting is unexpected.

Comment: The solution on you approach is only when I create separate sphinx attribute for each of interests and in each of them do compatition of is main interest or no and then sorting by user choosen interest. But its huge redundancy.

Comment: I wonder if you thinking this would be a attribute created in the index - no, dont mean that. Its a virtual attribute, only created during the query. One attribute (scalar, or MVA) for ALL the main interests. The 'IF()' is a sphinx function, not mysql.